# Cannot change the color of variable in dir_colors

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors

I use a fork of [the st terminal](https://st.suckless.org/). When I type anything after a dollar sign, I cannot see the text because it blends in with the background. I use `dir_colors` to change colors of different file types.  But I don't know the definition of that particular type.

For example, suppose I type `$TERM`. Until `$TER`, the color is similar to the background color but after typing `$TERM`, it becomes red. It is in a different color when it is typed as a parameter, after a command. I cannot figure out how to switch the color.

Comment: Sounds like you're using some sort of zsh syntax highlighting plugin. Does `print -rC1 - ${(k)functions[(R)*region_highlight*]}` return anything?

Comment: What's that `dir_colors`? Do you mean the `dircolors` utility shipped with GNU `ls` used to help set the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable used by GNU `ls` (and possibly zsh's `zsh/complist` module)?

Comment: yeah it uses zsh plugins, but i control it with dircolors (sorry for the typo). The ouput of `print -rC1 - ${(k)functions[(R)*region_highlight*]} ` is as follows: ```_zsh_highlight
_zsh_autosuggest_highlight_reset
_zsh_highlight_main_highlighter_highlight_list
_zsh_highlight_add_highlight
_zsh_highlight_apply_zle_highlight
_zsh_highlight_regexp_highlighter_loop
_zsh_highlight_pattern_highlighter_loop
_zsh_autosuggest_highlight_apply
_zsh_highlight_main_highlighter_highlight_argument
_zsh_highlight_main_add_many_region_highlights
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relevant information along with all customisations to the zsh highlight plugin that you're applying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) for pointing me in the right direction.

I used `dircolors` but did not remember it was the `zsh` syntax highlighting which enabled the highlighting as I described.

The same problem was already answered [over here](https://superuser.com/questions/1795221/zsh-syntax-highlighting-writes-parameter-expansion-in-black).